# Stuck in pointers, printing the vector of class objects with vector of pointers to the output console

Tags: c++, class, c++11, pointers, vector

I am new to programming and stuck with an example.

1. I have created a class ptr_generator that creates an array of pointers through its constructor. Here these pointers point to a vector of doubles.
2. Then a vector myvec of class ptr_generator type is created.

I am having problems printing out the initial vector of doubles that the pointers are pointed to.

Can someone please help me in figuring this out?

```cpp
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

struct ptr_generator 
{
    ptr_generator ( std::vector<double> v1 , std::vector<double> v2)
    {
        std::array<std::vector<double>* , 2> ptr_arr {{&v1, &v2}};
    }
};

//Myarr is a vector of ptr_generator class objects

using myvec = std::vector< ptr_generator> ;

myvec myfunction (std::vector<double> v1, std::vector<double> v2 )
{
    myvec MyVector;
    
    MyVector.push_back(ptr_generator(v1, v2));
    
    std::cout << MyVector[0]<< std::endl;
    
    return MyVector;
}


int main()
{
    
    std::vector<double> vec1 { 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.1};
    std::vector<double> vec2 { 1.0, 4.0, 6.1, 2.1};
    
    myfunction (vec1, vec2);
  
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘myvec myfunction(std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>)’:
main.cpp:33:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka ptr_generator}’)
     std::cout << MyVector[0]<< std::endl;
```

Comment: I have seen a lot of posts on printing class objects but still could not solve the issue here. apology for answering the basic question but I want to learn the insights of these concepts here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Paul for commenting. 
I have tried this and added

`ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ptr_generator& ptr_obj)
{
    os << ptr_obj.ptr_arr[0] << " " << ptr_obj.ptr_arr[1] << " " << ptr_obj.ptr_arr[2];
    return os;
}`

and it is returning me the addresses. Can you please tell me how can I print my original vectors vec1 and vec2 in the output console using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overload the `operator<<` function for `ptr_generator`.

The `std::array` is not stored outside of the constructor, so we'll add that as a member of the `ptr_generator` class. Then we will do two loops; One to loop over the array and one to loop over the vectors. As the array holds vector pointers, we need to dereference them before iterating them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

struct ptr_generator
{
    using vec_dbl = vector<double>;
    ptr_generator(vec_dbl& v1, vec_dbl& v2)
        : storage_({ &v1, &v2 })
    {}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ptr_generator& pg)
    {
        for (auto v : pg.storage_)
        {
            for (auto d : *v)
            {
                os << d << ' ';
            }
            os << '\n';
        }
        return os;
    }
private:
    array<vec_dbl*, 2> storage_;
};

using myvec = vector<ptr_generator>;

myvec myfunction(ptr_generator::vec_dbl & v1, ptr_generator::vec_dbl & v2)
{
    myvec myvec;

    myvec.push_back(ptr_generator(v1, v2));

    cout << myvec[0] << endl;

    return myvec;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> vec1{ 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.1 };
    vector<double> vec2{ 1.0, 4.0, 6.1, 2.1 };

    myfunction(vec1, vec2);
}
```

Another thing to note, is that I changed the constructor and `myfunction` to take the vectors by reference. As they were, they were taken by value and so getting copied between functions. Then in the constructor when you took the addresses of the vectors, you were taking the addresses of the copied vectors not the originals. This is undefined behaviour as those vectors will go out of scope.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Ronney for the detailed description and for changing the code. Much appreciated!
Can you please suggest to me any particular link to study these concepts in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here that's not going to work.

First off, `myvec`, and consequently `MyVector` is a `std::vector<ptr_generator>`, we can agree on that, yes?

So when you write `std::cout << MyVector[0];` then what you're really doing is calling `cout` on a `ptr_generator`.  But `ptr_generator` has no `operator<<` that can operate on it.  You're going to have to write one.

When you do that, you'll find that your `ptr_generator` class needs a lot of work.  First off, you'll want a member variable to store the data you passed in.  But moreover, you ***cannot*** take and store the address of function arguments, as you do in `{{&v1, &v2}}`.  You need to make copies of them if you want to store them.

Comment: thanks @Tumbleweed53, that is of great help and will give me a lot to learn